# sshd with multiple match sections, override settings

Tags: configuration, ssh, sshd

I have the situation where sshd should permit sftp only access to a group of users.

This is easily done by adding a match section like

```
Match Group groupname
    ChrootDirectory /srv/ftp
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Now I need to exclude one user that is a member of this group. He should have normal shell access.

```
Match User username
    ChrootDirectory ???
    ForceCommand ???
```

What do I set here?
Is it possible to unset configuration directives previuosly set with another matching section?

Answer (score 11):

First apply the settings to the group, excluding user "username;" then apply (other) settings to user "username." If you do not use the `ForceCommand` setting for user "username," it is not applied.

```
Match Group groupname User !username
   ChrootDirectory /srv/ftp
   ForceCommand internal-sftp
Match User username
   PasswordAuthentication yes
```

You can also use different settings if the user logs in from different IP addresses.

```bash
# all users except username1 and username2 default to sftp
Match User *,!username1,!username2
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp -f LOCAL0 -l INFO

# normal ssh allowed for users username1 and username2 from the local network
Match User username1,username2 Address 192.168.0.0/16
    PasswordAuthentication yes

# users username1 and username2 not allowed from other networks
Match User username1,username2 Address *,!192.168.0.0/16
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand /usr/sbin/nologin
```

Comment: Your second example is exactly what I need, and -- therefore -- much appreciated. To group the "bad" users together, I introduced a group, e.g., `badusers`:  
    `Match Group badusers Address *,!192.168.0.0/16
        PasswordAuthentication no`

Answer (score 9):

Don't add an extra `Match User` section. Instead, exclude the user by excluding him from the original `Match`.

```
Match Group groupname User !username
    ChrootDirectory /srv/ftp
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

All criteria on the `Match` line must be satisfied for the section to be applied.

As [Nicolas Mommaerts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/326206/nicolas-mommaerts) discovered, there's [a bug with negative-only patterns](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=121945), and you may need to first include everyone with `*`:

```
Match Group groupname User *,!username
    ChrootDirectory /srv/ftp
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Comment: For everyone else who stumbles upon this, I just couldn't get it to work until I read https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=121945. Turns out there is a bug in the pattern matching and you need to do "Match Group groupname, User *,!username", after I did that it worked immediately as expected.

Comment: @NicolasMommaerts With SSH Config, [the doc says](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html) _"**Criteria** may be negated by prepending an exclamation mark (‘!’)."_ Can you do that with SSHD as well? `Match Group foo !User bar baz`

Comment: ^ SSHD Config [says "yes"](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html) _"The match patterns […] may use the wildcard and negation operators described in the **PATTERNS** section of `ssh_config`(5)."_

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is putting the user rule first:

```
Match user lee
    ChrootDirectory /mnt/s3
    ForceCommand internal-sftp

Match group ftp
    ChrootDirectory /home/%u
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Match Group groupname User *,!username
ChrootDirectory /srv/ftp
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Comment: Duplicate code from [the oldest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10831308/241211)